# Where does the node check the supporting chain for the transaction?

Tags: corda

When and where does the node check the backchain of a transaction?

Of course, the node does this when verifying a transaction. When you Look at TransactionBuilder.verify, it *looks like* it just looks at the "current" transaction, not the historic ones that led up to the input states in the current transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is facilitated whenever you receive a stateref or transaction.

`ResolveTransactionFlow` calls `verify` for every transaction it finds - that's the flow that fetches the backchain for a transaction